# Qooxdoo -- How to bind icon to an item of a VirtualTree

Tags: qooxdoo

I'm using a VirtualTree as a layer selector for a mapping application, and I'm trying to have a "Layer" or "File" show a green icon when a layer is active and a grey icon when it is not.

Can you...

1. Set the icon of a selection? or
2. Bind an icon of an item of a VirtualTree to a boolean property of an array?

I see there is a property for: iconOptions that takes a map and this references qx.data.SingleValueBinding, but how to actually implement it is stumping me.  My tree is getting created using:

```
var store = new qx.data.store.Json(url);
store.bind("model", tree, "model");
```

I tried:

```
tree.setIconPath("icon");
```

but that requires that I have an icon property for every element of my JSON file to display the Folder/File and doesn't allow for the multiple (on/off) capabilities.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at [virtual tree demo](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/demobrowser/index.html#virtual~Tree_Dynamic.html). Using the setIconOption  you could specify a convertor takeing other data into account when deciding what type of icon to set.

Comment: Thanks Tobi, sometimes it's just a matter of finding those examples. In the end, I had to add another key to my JSON and I used the model to set the icon value based on if my new "loaded" key was true or false.